# Need reducer to add to every *child* item of my state a single object

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I have an ngrx store (in typescript) and i want in my EntityAdapter reducer to check for an action and then add to every child of my item in the store the payload of the action. Example below

We have an array of objects in the state, and each object has one property, lets call it X that is an array as well.

```
[
 {x:[]}
,{x:[]}
,{x:[]}
]
```

What i want to end up with is:

```
[
 {x:[{y}]}
,{x:[{y}]}
,{x:[{y}]}
]
```

after the reducer runs

Here is the crocks of it:

```
export const permissionWithRolesReducer = createReducer(initialPermissionWithRolesState,

  on(actions.loadPermissionsWithRolesSuccess,(state,{permissionWithRoles: permissionWithRoles}) =>{ 
    return permissionWithRolesAdapter.upsertMany(permissionWithRoles, state)}),

    on(actions.addRole,(state,{newRole: newRole}) =>{ 
      return permissionWithRolesAdapter.???}));
```

The result is to add the role under the permissions.

The store contains a list of permissions. 
Each permission contains a list of roles it applies to.
When we add a new role i want to add it to every permission in my store.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`, which maps over every entity in the collection (similar to `[].map()` in javascript).

```
return permissionWithRolesAdapter.map(entity => ({ ...entity, y: action.y }), state)
```

Comment: Hello @timdeschryver , i am pretty new to this but i tried your solution and i have an error -> 

    on(actions.loadPermissionsWithRolesSuccess,(state,{permissionWithRoles: permissionWithRoles}) =>{ 
      return permissionWithRolesAdapter.map( a=> ({ ...a , rolesForPermission : permissionWithRoles })));

Error - expected 2 parameters but got one, a definition for state was not provided.

Comment: See updated answer, you also have to provide your state as 2nd param

Comment: Hello man, Thank you for your answer. You helped me greatly! I managed to fix it with the following code:

    on(actions.addRoleSuccess,(state,{newRole}) =>{ 
      return permissionWithRolesAdapter.map(u => ({...u, rolesForPermission: [...u.rolesForPermission, newRole]}),state)}));